# Removing a column twice by setting it to "NULL" triggers an error in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

An error caused by mistyping of "up" button:

```
require(data.table)
DT = data.table(x=rep(letters[1:3], each=3L), y=c(1,3,6), v=1:9, key="x,y")
DT[ , z := 42L][]    # add 'z' column by reference
DT[ , z := NULL][]   # remove "z" column
DT["a", z := NULL][] # attempt to re-remove "z" for certain rows -- error
# Error in `[.data.table`(DT, "a", `:=`(z, NULL)) : 
#   When deleting columns, i should not be provided
# In addition: Warning message:
# In `[.data.table`(DT, "a", `:=`(z, NULL)) :
#   Adding new column 'z' then assigning NULL (deleting it).
DT[, z := NULL][]
# Error in ans[[target]] : subscript out of bounds
DT
#    x y  v    z
# 1: a 1 42 NULL
# 2: a 3 42 NULL
# 3: a 6 42 NULL
# 4: b 1  4 NULL
# 5: b 3  5 NULL
# 6: b 6  6 NULL
# 7: c 1  7 NULL
# 8: c 3  8 NULL
# 9: c 6  9 NULL
```

How to remove the "z" column in a simple way?

Not like

```
DT <- DT[, 1:3, with=F].
```

Comment: I don't understand the question here. You yourself removed the `z` column "*in a simple way*" using `DT[,z:=NULL]`, so what seems to be the problem now? I also can't reproduce this behaviour you are mentioning. Do you have the latest version of `data.table` (v 1.9.6)?

Comment: Sorry that I didn't clearly describe the problem. After running `DT[, z:=NULL]`, there is a rerun of `DT[, z:=NULL]`. Then a column of NULL named "z" generated in "DT", and it can't be removed by `DT[, z:=NULL]`. I do have version 1.9.6.

Comment: Deleting a column for certain rows does not make sense. Either you've a column or not.

Comment: I can replicate this (I, like many others, am 'stuck' on 1.9.4 thx to what newer versions break), but why would one keep doing `z := NULL`? Regardless, you are probably asking this since you are left with a `data.table` with a `z` column you don't want and can't seem to get rid of it. `mdt$z <- NULL` ought to work.

Comment: @hrbrmstr OP said he using v 1.9.6. Regardless, doesn't `DT[,z:=NULL]` work on v 1.9.4?? Why would you do `mdt$z <- NULL`?

Comment: I still don't understand why would you do `DT["a",z:=NULL]` after you already did `DT[,z:=NULL]`

Comment: I didn't do it on purpose. There is a mistyping, and I am curious about how to offset it.

Comment: @DavidArenburg (a) I was typing as that news came in; (b) running through those steps, the last `DT[,z:=NULL]` does not, in fact, work.

Comment: Please provide `sessionInfo()`

Comment: "up", then "enter", that's it.

Comment: I am very sorry, my version is not the latest one.other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.9.4 ff_2.2-13        bit_1.1-12

Comment: Run `install.packages("data.table") ; library(data.table)` and try your code again

Answer (score 3):

On the latest version, `v1.9.6`, this is what I get:

```
require(data.table) # v1.9.6
DT[, z := 42]      ## adds 'z' by reference

DT[, z := NULL]    ## removes 'z' column

DT["a", z := NULL] ## sensible error, as the operation doesn't make sense
# Error in `[.data.table`(DT, "a", `:=`(z, NULL)) :
#   When deleting columns, i should not be provided

DT[, z := NULL]
# Warning message:
# In `[.data.table`(DT, , `:=`(z, NULL)) :
#   Adding new column 'z' then assigning NULL (deleting it).

DT
#    x y v
# 1: a 1 1
# 2: a 3 2
# 3: a 6 3
# 4: b 1 4
# 5: b 3 5
# 6: b 6 6
# 7: c 1 7
# 8: c 3 8
# 9: c 6 9
```

When asking about undesired behaviours, it is essential to provide your version. It's very likely to be fixed on recent releases. So the best way to save everyone's time is to upgrade to the latest version first, test it there, and then post it here. If you'd like to be really helpful, then you'd also test it on the [devel version](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) and file an issue if you're able to reproduce the undesired behaviour.